# Is there any value to search a column of values in excel in another column

Tags: excel, search, vlookup

Is there any way to search a column of values in excel in another column. Column A is text values and Column B may contain column A in its cell values.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question.

Comment: Teylyn is right, it sounds straightforward but unless we can see what you want to do we can't help. Post samples of your data, possibly as image links?

Answer (score 0):

Use VLOOKUP or if you want to search horizontally (through a line) you can use HLOOKUP